# slangword from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

```
import re

def main():
    slang_file = [line.strip().split(":") for line in open("dictionary.txt")]
    slang = {k:v for k, v in slang_file}
    sentence = input("enter a sentence to translate\n")
    print(re.sub(r"\w+", lambda m: slang.get(m.group(0), m.group(0)), sentence))

main()
```

Dictionary  contain of this:

```
meee:me

r:are
```

But I always got this type of error:

```
slang = {k:v for k, v in slang_file}
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The output that i want is like this:

```
r u hungry

are you hungry
```

Comment: It looks like one of lines in `dictionary.txt` is incorrect. Try debug printing  `slang_file`  - `print(slang_file)` before `slang = ...` to see if lines are correct.

Comment: thanks.
when I try it, nothing error.
the outpt are below:
[['gooodd', 'good'], ['friendz', 'friends'], ['meh', 'me']}

Comment: can you also post content of `dictionary.txt` If output of `print(slang_file)` is exactly as you posted (apart from `]` instead of `}` at the end of line) then this error should not occur. Either your `dictionary.txt` is longer and contains some more lines or you have different code than the one you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the lines in your `dictionary.txt` may contain more than one colon, so you should limit the number of splits when splitting the input:

```
slang_file = [line.strip().split(":", 1) for line in open("dictionary.txt")]
```

Comment: thanks, that's true. in my dictionary there is line that contain two :, that cause an error.